# using public key encryption in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption

I am trying to use a public key provided to me by web service developer to securely transfer data. I have tried hard but I am not able to find any working example with latest swift version. I have coded it like following(with help from [here](https://gist.github.com/mdelete/d9dbc320d5de347c2a85):

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge){
    if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
        var localTrust: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecTrust?>
        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let serverPublicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(serverTrust)
        let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pinning-certificate", ofType: "der")!)
        let localCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, certificateData!)
        let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()

        if SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(localCertificate!, policy, localTrust) == errSecSuccess {
            let localTrustRef = localTrust
            let localPublicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(localTrustRef)!
            if (localPublicKey as AnyObject).isEqual(serverPublicKey as! AnyObject) {
                print("trusted")
                return challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge!(challenge)
            }
        }
    }
    print("not trusted")
    return challenge.sender!.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
   }
```

But I am getting following error during compilation in SecTrustCreateWithCertificates() and SecTrustCopyPublicKey():
**Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer>')**.

**Edit 1:** I have changed my code to following and now my code is executed but server is not receiving any request:

```
func extractIdentity(certData:NSData) -> IdentityAndTrust {
    var identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust!
    var securityError:OSStatus = errSecSuccess

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MobileAppClient", ofType: "pfx")!
    let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
    let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
    let options : NSDictionary = [key : "client"]

    //create variable for holding security information
    //var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil

    var items : CFArray?
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(PKCS12Data, options, &items)

        if securityError == errSecSuccess {
        let certItems:CFArray = items as CFArray!;
        let certItemsArray:Array = certItems as Array
        let dict:AnyObject? = certItemsArray.first;
        if let certEntry:Dictionary = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            // grab the identity
            let identityPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["identity"];
            let secIdentityRef:SecIdentityRef = identityPointer as! SecIdentityRef!;
            print("\(identityPointer)  :::: \(secIdentityRef)")
            // grab the trust
            let trustPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["trust"];
            let trustRef:SecTrustRef = trustPointer as! SecTrustRef;
            print("\(trustPointer)  :::: \(trustRef)")
            // grab the cert
            let chainPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["chain"];
            identityAndTrust = IdentityAndTrust(identityRef: secIdentityRef, trust: trustRef, certArray:  chainPointer! as! NSArray);
        }
    }
    return identityAndTrust;
}
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge){

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {

        let serverTrust:SecTrustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let certificate: SecCertificateRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0)!
        let remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRetain(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate))!
        let cerPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Certificates", ofType: "cer")!
        let localCertificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile:cerPath)!

        challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

                    if (remoteCertificateData.isEqualToData(localCertificateData) == true) {
            let credential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: serverTrust)

            challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

        } else {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            return challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge!(challenge)
        }

    }
    else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
    {

        let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Certificates", ofType: "p12")!
        let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!


        let identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust = self.extractIdentity(PKCS12Data);



        let urlCredential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(
            identity: identityAndTrust.identityRef,
            certificates: identityAndTrust.certArray as? [AnyObject],
            persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession);
        challenge.sender?.useCredential(urlCredential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer given below:

```
 func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

   if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {


    let serverTrust:SecTrustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
    let certificate: SecCertificateRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0)!
    let remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRetain(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate))!
    let cerPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("xyz.com", ofType: "cer")!
    let localCertificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile:cerPath)!


        if (remoteCertificateData.isEqualToData(localCertificateData) == true) {
            let credential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: serverTrust)

            challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)


            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))

        } else {

            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }
    else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
    {

        let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("client", ofType: "p12")!
        let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!


        let identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust = self.extractIdentity(PKCS12Data);



            let urlCredential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(
                identity: identityAndTrust.identityRef,
                certificates: identityAndTrust.certArray as? [AnyObject],
                persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession);

            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, urlCredential);




    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
  }
```

Add the following Code

```
 struct IdentityAndTrust {

    var identityRef:SecIdentityRef
    var trust:SecTrustRef
    var certArray:AnyObject
}

func extractIdentity(certData:NSData) -> IdentityAndTrust {
    var identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust!
    var securityError:OSStatus = errSecSuccess

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("client", ofType: "p12")!
    let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
    let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
    let options : NSDictionary = [key : "xyz"]
    //create variable for holding security information
    //var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil

    var items : CFArray?

     securityError = SecPKCS12Import(PKCS12Data, options, &items)

    if securityError == errSecSuccess {
        let certItems:CFArray = items as CFArray!;
        let certItemsArray:Array = certItems as Array
        let dict:AnyObject? = certItemsArray.first;
        if let certEntry:Dictionary = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            // grab the identity
            let identityPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["identity"];
            let secIdentityRef:SecIdentityRef = identityPointer as! SecIdentityRef!;
            print("\(identityPointer)  :::: \(secIdentityRef)")
            // grab the trust
            let trustPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["trust"];
            let trustRef:SecTrustRef = trustPointer as! SecTrustRef;
            print("\(trustPointer)  :::: \(trustRef)")
            // grab the cert
            let chainPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["chain"];
            identityAndTrust = IdentityAndTrust(identityRef: secIdentityRef, trust: trustRef, certArray:  chainPointer!);
        }
    }
    return identityAndTrust;
}
```

Comment: Hi Karlos, I am getting error in following line: let serverTrust:SecTrustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust! I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: sorry for replying after many days but client certificate was not installed on server earlier, it just got configured yesterday

Comment: I think the backend server is not sending the server trust in the challenge or other reason might be because of cipher suits. Please also check that your backend server supports the following cipher suits supported by Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW35    Search for "Requirements for Connecting Using ATS" in this link

Comment: Also check your settings in the info.plist as given in the answer of the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073822/how-to-make-a-https-request-to-a-server-in-swift/34080951#34080951

Comment: ATS is working for me as I was using services earlier, now server guy has added certificate based authentication and given me a key to access

Comment: btw when I printed serverTrust in my log it is nil, so should I now ask server guy to send serverTrust informations?

Comment: Yes. Can you upload a sample code in GitHub with your server certificates and url?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot share certificate and url here as it is a confidential information and I am under a confidentiality agreement with my company. I will ask server guy to send serverTrust information in server connection.

Comment: Its okay, I understand.

Comment: Hi Karlos, I have made changes to my code and I have added it as Edit in my question, Now complete code of authentication challange method is executed but server is not able to receive any request. Do you have idea what could be the problem here.

Comment: Until the SSL authentication is completed successfully, It won't reaches to your backend server. By completion I mean the successful authentication at TLS layer. Can you add a break point on " if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {" and when the code reaches this break point type "po challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod" in the debug screen and let me know what output your are getting?

Comment: It is NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate

Comment: Your backend server team has also added the client authentication on the server side. You need to add the client certificate (example: client.p12) in your project. I have updated the answer for this. After making this changes it should work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97512/discussion-between-karlos-and-pankaj).

Comment: Could you please help me extract the subject from the certificate? The chain is AnyObject, I don't really know what datatype it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are 2 problems:

1) To cast `UnsafeMutablePointer` you should call `localTrust.memory` but it will give you next error
2) Next error will give you that pointer in uninitialized, I think you can use code like this:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge){
    if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
        var localTrust: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecTrust?> = nil
        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let serverPublicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(serverTrust)
        let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pinning-certificate", ofType: "der")!)
        let localCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, certificateData!)
        let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()

        if SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(localCertificate!, policy, localTrust) == errSecSuccess {
            let localTrustRef = localTrust
            let localPublicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(localTrustRef.memory!)!
            if (localPublicKey as AnyObject).isEqual(serverPublicKey as! AnyObject) {
                print("trusted")
                return challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge!(challenge)
            }
        }
    }
    print("not trusted")
    return challenge.sender!.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
}
```

P.s. it's NOT safe to forcecast `optional`. Plese consider using `if let` statement

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have used your code and I am not getting any error during compilation but I get Bad Access error on runtime on line: let localPublicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(localTrustRef.memory!)!