# How to make a HTTPS request to a server in swift?

Tags: swift, ssl, swift2

I am having server certificate and client certificate that needs to be included in the request to authenticate the server is there any tutorial or reference to make such requests in swift

i am able to do in java but i am new to swift i want a resource in swift to authenticate and make requests to server

my java code to make ssl configuration:

```
SslConfigurator  sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance().securityProtocol("protocol")
                .keyStoreFile("/path").keyStorePassword("password").keyStoreType("JKS")
                .trustStoreFile("path");
```

Comment: Swift itself doesn't offer networking APIs. Perhaps you're really asking how to make an SSL connection in an iOS app, using one of the many frameworks available on that platform? Try perusing [Apple's developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/#section=Topics&topic=Networking%20%26amp%3B%20Internet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using the iOS native library. You can use the following function for connection and server certificate and client certificate authentication:

```
func ConnectionRequest(jsonString:NSDictionary, callback: (NSDictionary, String!) -> Void) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://example.com:9222")!)

    var result = NSDictionary()

    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: [])
    } catch{
        request.HTTPBody = nil
    }
    request.timeoutInterval = 20.0 //(number as! NSTimeInterval)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-encoding")

    let configuration =
    NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration,
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    print("--------------------------------NSURLSession Request-------------------------------------------------->:\n \(jsonString)")
    print(NSDate())


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                print("response was not 200: \(response)")
                return
            }
            else
            {
                print("response was 200: \(response)")

                print("Data for 200: \(data)")

                // In the callback you can return the data/response 
                callback(data, nil)
                return
            }
        }
        if (error != nil) {
            print("error request:\n \(error)")
            //Here you can return the error and handle it accordingly
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Following are the code changes which work fine with Self Signed SSL certificate

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {


    let serverTrust:SecTrustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
    let certificate: SecCertificateRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0)!
    let remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRetain(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate))!
    let cerPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example.com", ofType: "cer")!
    let localCertificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile:cerPath)!


        if (remoteCertificateData.isEqualToData(localCertificateData) == true) {
            let credential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: serverTrust)

            challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)


            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))

        } else {

            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }
    else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
    {

        let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("client", ofType: "p12")!
        let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!


        let identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust = self.extractIdentity(PKCS12Data);



            let urlCredential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(
                identity: identityAndTrust.identityRef,
                certificates: identityAndTrust.certArray as? [AnyObject],
                persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession);

            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, urlCredential);




    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}

 struct IdentityAndTrust {

    var identityRef:SecIdentityRef
    var trust:SecTrustRef
    var certArray:AnyObject
}

func extractIdentity(certData:NSData) -> IdentityAndTrust {
    var identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust!
    var securityError:OSStatus = errSecSuccess

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("client", ofType: "p12")!
    let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
    let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
    let options : NSDictionary = [key : "xyz"]
    //create variable for holding security information
    //var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil

    var items : CFArray?

     securityError = SecPKCS12Import(PKCS12Data, options, &items)

    if securityError == errSecSuccess {
        let certItems:CFArray = items as CFArray!;
        let certItemsArray:Array = certItems as Array
        let dict:AnyObject? = certItemsArray.first;
        if let certEntry:Dictionary = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            // grab the identity
            let identityPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["identity"];
            let secIdentityRef:SecIdentityRef = identityPointer as! SecIdentityRef!;
            print("\(identityPointer)  :::: \(secIdentityRef)")
            // grab the trust
            let trustPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["trust"];
            let trustRef:SecTrustRef = trustPointer as! SecTrustRef;
            print("\(trustPointer)  :::: \(trustRef)")
            // grab the cert
            let chainPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["chain"];
            identityAndTrust = IdentityAndTrust(identityRef: secIdentityRef, trust: trustRef, certArray:  chainPointer!);
        }
    }
    return identityAndTrust;
}
```

Changes done in the info.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        </dict>
        <key>amazonaws.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        </dict>
        <key>xyz.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: You have to just add "client.p12" and "example.com.cer" certificate files in your project.

Comment: The app will automatically use it?

Comment: Yes, it will take it automatically. I am doing this in my app and its working fine,

Comment: Excellent and very useful answer, worked right away in my app. Many thanks!