# Figuring out to set up HTTPS

Tags: ios, flask, amazon-ec2, https, alamofire

I'm a relatively new programmer to backend security so very much in the dark about how to set up HTTPS. I'm currently writing an IOS app that is sending http requests to my public EC2 backend domain, however I'm trying to transition this to HTTPS. Right now the backend is running on the developmental Flask server using HTTPS with a self signed certificate. However the problem is that on the IOS app side, it rejects this as invalid so I'm unable to test HTTPS dependant features. I tried to use the domain exception with the infoplist and ip.xip.io but it still complains that someone could be pretending to be this address. Could someone list in a very systematic way how I should approach building this out,i.e are there any free CA's, do I need a cert from a CA, and how to go about properly connecting the app and backend with HTTPS using my ec2 public ip.

Comment: Hope these help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073822/how-to-make-a-https-request-to-a-server-in-swift
https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the iOS app will authenticate properly using a free community certificate. Investigate free certificate authorities, like letsencrypt. There are several. These work like the commercial CAs such as GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest solution was to just use Ngrok